# Slave I/O for channel error connecting to master Error_code: 2003

Tags: mysql, replication, errors, phpmyadmin, master-master-replication

i am trying a master master replication mysql with phpmyadmin using wamp server.
everything seems to be fine, the configuration was well done, so the server is slave and master at the same time ,

but when i did the command `show slave status\G` i have this result :

```
    mysql> Show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 10.24.60.213
                  Master_User: user
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File:
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 4
               Relay_Log_File: MUL-N003-relay-bin.000017
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File:
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 0
              Relay_Log_Space: 154
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 2003
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'user@10.24.60.213:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 4
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 0
                  Master_UUID:
             Master_Info_File: c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.26\data\master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 190626 13:44:11
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

i've tried to add bind-address='....' and it doesn't work, i did also bind-address = 0.0.0.0, doesn't work too ..

when i did a test of the 3306 port, it seems like it's not associated with TCP protocol..

any ideas to solve this problem please !

Comment: Are both servers the same MySQL version? Are you getting this result on both servers or just one? Does `user` have `REPLICATION CLIENT` and `REPLICATION SLAVE` privileges on both servers? Can you connect to the master from the slave (`mysql -u user -p -h 10.24.60.213 -P 3306`)?

Comment: 1- Yes, both servers same MySQL version, 2- Yes i am getting the same result on both of them, 3- Yes, user have replication client and replication slave, 4- i don't know where i should try this cmd line, is it the correct path (C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.26>mysql -u user -p -h 10.24.60.213 -P 3306) )

Comment: I'd would think any command prompt would work, but if WAMP bin folder isn't in the path environment variable, go to whichever folder contains the `mysql` executable and run it. I have not used WAMP. MySQL is installed like any other program on our Windows servers. Another thing to check is verify you didn't restrict what hosts `user` could connect from. `SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'user';` I do restrict to the same subnet (e.g., 192.168.75.%)

Comment: thanks for ur Answer, i just resolved the problem , i reset the configuration of master and slave , and I started it all from the beginning, my master/slave replication works finally, but when i switch to master/master replication it crashes, i have a 1141 error, it's about user privileges, i don't know how to solve it yet, do you have any idea plz ?

Comment: Hard to say with what little info you provided. What is the full error message? I'm puzzled since you say master/slave works, which is all that is needed for master/master. You just do the same commands on the other server. What command did you run on which server to "switch" to master-master? At what point did you get the error? It suggests that your slave user doesn't really have the privileges you claimed it did (on one of the servers at least.